# Find location of a pattern of bits in a binary array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary, pattern-matching

I have an array of binary data with long stretches of ones and zeros and I want to find the indices of when it changes.

```
a = [ 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
```

I want to search for `[1 0]` and `[0 1]` to find the transition points. I'd like to avoid long loops to find these if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: You most certainly want to use the [`diff`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
b = diff(a);                     % (assuming 'a' is a vector)
oneFromZero = find(b ==  1) + 1; % vector of indices of a '1' preceded by a '0'
zeroFromOne = find(b == -1) + 1; % vector of indices of a '0' preceded by a '1'
```

Depending on what you want exactly, you may or may not want to add `1` to the resulting arrays of indices.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! This worked beautifully :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

```
d = a(1:end-1) - a(2:end);
ind = find(d);
```

Here, `d` will be `1` where you have a `... 1 0 ...` in your bit string and it will be `-1` where you have a `... 0 1 ...`. All the other elements in `d` will be `0`, since, at those positions, the bits are equal to their neighbour.

With this in place, you can use `find` to get the indices where these two patterns occur. The whole procedure is of `O(n)` complexity, where `n=length(a)`, since it requires two passes through `a`.

For `a = [ 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]` the above code computes `ind = [5 11]`.

Comment: `d = a(1:end-1) - a(2:end);` can be simplified to `d = -diff(a);`.

Comment: Is there any performance/speed difference between these two options?

Answer (score 2):

To search for an **arbitrary pattern of zeros and ones**:

1. You can compute a [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) ([`conv`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html)) of the two sequences in *bipolar* (±1) form and then find the maxima. Since the convolution flips one of the inputs, it has to be *flipped* to undo that:

   ```
   a = [ 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1];
   pattern = [0 1 1];
   result = find(conv(2*a-1, 2*pattern(end:-1:1)-1, 'valid')==numel(pattern));
   ```

   In this example

   ```
   result =
       11
   ```

   which means that `[0 1 1]` appears in `a` only once, namely at index `11`.
2. A simpler approach is to use [`strfind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html), exploiting the *undocumented* fact that this function can be applied to numeric vectors:

   ```
   result = strfind(a, pattern);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'll keep this in mind in case I need to find a longer pattern.

Comment: I haven't run any benchmark, but I would guess your approach using `conv` is more efficient than mine.

Comment: @Jubobs I doubt it. For the specific OP case (`[1 0 ]` and `[0 1]`) `diff` should be very fast

Comment: I went with diff because I'm just looking for changes in long sequences of ones and zeros (array of valid flags), but this looks like a great option for finding other patterns. Thanks again

Comment: @ErinGoBragh Welcome! That would have been my preferred approach too, for your specific case